# JavaScript: синтаксис «знак равно + знак больше» (=>)

Tags: javascript

Что означает синтаксис `=>` в JavaScript?

Пример с [JSR](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) (JavaScript.Ru):

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('result');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Тоже самое что и `function() {`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, точно, сразу не просматривается. А цель ввода такого синтаксиса и поддержки браузерами (или это с древних времён ещё?) не подскажите?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions   прочитайте. Полезно будет)   покороче будет, а смысл тот же. ну и нюанс с this ... там же прочитать можно

Comment: @w3lifer ES6 друг... ES6... Там много классных плюх, классы, наследования. Все по красоте, многое реализовано в babel. Можешь почитать, и пользоваться.

Comment: @Den напишите Ваш комментарий, как ответ с пояснениями.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский или Вы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это новый синтаксис функций. Кроме того как он выглядит имеет так же несколько особенностей.

Самое главное отличие, что он автоматически использует **this** из замыкания, где метод определен. Например:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() {
    return this;
  },
  arr: () => {
    return this;
  }
};


obj.foo(); // obj
obj.arr(); // window
```

Вторая особенность, что метод имеет краткую лямбда форму, когда выражение после стрелочки является возвращаемым значением.

```
var а = () => 1 // функция, всегда возвращающая единицу
// Эквивалентно (кроме this контекста)
var a = function() { return 1; }
var b = x => x + 1
// Эквивалентно
var b = function(x) { return x + 1; }
```

В случае нуля или нескольких параметров нужны скобки вокруг аргументов

```
 var c = (x,y,x) => x * y * x
```

Стоит выделить возврат объекта

```
var foo = (x) => ({ field: x })
```

Обратите внимание на круглые скобки вокруг тела функции, это одна из проблем нового синтаксиса, потому как почти такой же код:

```
var foo = (x) => { field: x }
```

является валидным, но делает совсем не то, что вы хотите.

В случае когда выражений больше чем одно, то необходимые фигурные скобки вокруг тела функции. При этом значение возвращать надо явно с помощью return.

```
var foo = (a, b) => {
  if (a > b) return 1;
  else return 42;
};
```

Когда применять такие функции? Главных применения два.
Первый – сокращенный синтаксис в обратных вызовах.
Согласитесь, такое

```
myStringsArray
  .map(a => parseFloat(a))
  .reduce((b, c) => b + c, 0);
```

намного луче читается, чем

```
myStringsArray
  .map(function (a) { return parseFloat(a)})
  .reduce(function(b, c) { return b + c; }, 0);
```

Второе применение связанно с контекстом, классами и обратными вызовами.

```
var obj = {
  data: 1,
  sendToServer: function() {
    ajax(this.data, function(newData) {
      this.data = newData; // this !== obj
    });
  },
  sendToServerArrow: function() {
    ajax(this.data, (newData) => {
      this.data = newData; // this === obj
    });
  }
}

obj.sendToServer() // установит значение в window.data
obj.sendToServerArrow() // установит значение в obj.data
```

Стоит ли использовать такие функции?
Нужно помнить, что их поддержка далеко не во всех браузерах. Если вы используете трансплитеры, такие как babel, или пишете под nodejs (>4), то никаких преград нет, кроме возможной потери производительности (нужно мерить).

*Для себя я решил, что использую их везде, кроме определения функций в модуле.*